# How to get the text of the next tag? (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The html code is :

```
<div class="card border p-3">
               <span class="small text-muted">Contact<br></span>
               <div>Steven Cantrell</div>
               <div class="small">Department of Justice</div>
               <div class="small">Federal Bureau of Investigation</div>
               <!---->
               <!---->
               <!---->
               <div class="small"><a href="mailto:skcantrell@fbi.gov ">skcantrell@fbi.gov</a></div>
               <div class="small">256-313-8835</div>
            </div>
```

I want to get the output inside the `<div>` tag i.e. `Steven Cantrell` .

I need such a way that I should be able to get the contents of next tag. In this case, it is `'span',{'class':'small text-muted'}`

What I tried is :

```
rfq_name = soup.find('span',{'class':'small text-muted'})
print(rfq_name.next)
```

But this printed `Contact` instead of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, just change your print to: `print(rfq_name.find_next('div').text)`

Find the element that has the text `"Contact"`. Then use `.find_next()` to get the next `<div>` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="card border p-3">
               <span class="small text-muted">Contact<br></span>
               <div>Steven Cantrell</div>
               <div class="small">Department of Justice</div>
               <div class="small">Federal Bureau of Investigation</div>
               <!---->
               <!---->
               <!---->
               <div class="small"><a href="mailto:skcantrell@fbi.gov ">skcantrell@fbi.gov</a></div>
               <div class="small">256-313-8835</div>
            </div>'''
            
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
contact = soup.find(text='Contact').find_next('div').text
```

**Output:**

```
print(contact)
Steven Cantrell
```